# How to use 'Realise Instances' node without losing multiple colours on object

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a donut here which I have made. The sprinkles are made using geometry nodes and have NOT been applied to the object yet:

[image]

I would like to apply the geometry nodes and convert the sprinkles into 3D mesh. To do so, I have added a 'Realise' Instances node to my geometry nodes. Since without it, the sprinkles would disappear if I try to apply the geometry nodes.

[image]

However, the Realise Instances node has changed all the sprinkles to one colour. But it has randomised that colour over multiple donuts.

[image]

My end goal is to have multiple differnet coloured sprinkles on each donut whilst having the sprinkles converted to 3D mesh so it's not longer being made using geometry nodes.

What do I need to modify in my node tree?

I have attached the blender file below if you'd like to investigate:

[image]

Comment: Lol I was about to post the same solution as in duplicate :D